# Load .so library in LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, context

I want to use some C .so libraries for LuaTeX (LuaLaTeX and ConTeXt), as [limath](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/%7Elhf/ftp/lua/#limath). To be more specific, I want to do something like

```
%\documentclass{article} % LuaLaTeX
%\usepackage{luacode} % LuaLaTeX 
%\begin{luacode*} in LuaLaTeX
\startluacode % ConTeXt
--This works in Lua, but does not work in LuaTeX
imath = require "imath"
z = imath.new(3)
z = z^48 
\stopluacode
%\end{luacode*} in LuaLaTeX 
%\begin{document} % LuaLaTeX
\starttext
\directlua{tex.print(z)}
\stoptext 
%\end{document} % LuaLaTeX
```

I've read about recompiling LuaTeX or using a foreign library function, but I don't know how to implement those solutions. As a side question, I wonder if it is possible to load .so files in a manner like `dofile` for Lua libraries.

Comment: This should normally just work, but LuaTeX uses different search paths than "regular" Lua. So where is the `.so` file located?

Comment: In the same folder as the .tex file.

Comment: Also this code will require enabling `--shell-escape` starting with LuaTeX 1.12, so if ou recently updated LuaTeX you might want to try enabling that.

Comment: Do you actually get an error or do you just don't get any output?

Comment: I don't get any output. I enabled --shell-escape, but no output appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LuaTeX function allows you to pass a catcode table as first argument. So if the first argument is a number like in your example, is is not printed but instead interpreted as a catcode table.

You can avoid this by converting to a string first:

```
\documentclass{article} % LuaLaTeX
\usepackage{luacode} % LuaLaTeX 
\begin{luacode*}
imath = require "imath"
z = imath.new(3)
z = z^48
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}
\directlua{tex.print(tostring(z))}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked!!! Yay, thank you very much ❤️

Comment: You probably also want to switch to `tex.sprint` instead of `tex.print`.

Comment: @HenriMenke does that then still require `tostring()` or is it implied in that case?

Comment: @0xC0000022L You still want `tostring`.